# How do build and deploy WP8 app on device which is created from Mobile First 7.1?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I made simple Test app to check direct update in Mobile First 7.1.

Added WindowsPhone8 - Universal environment. Opened created native windows8 folder in Visual Studio. Now its showing three folders namely .Shared, .Windows8(Windows8.1) and .WindowsPhone8(WindowsPhone8.1).

Now I want to create xap of WP8 to deploy on device. How to do that? In 6.1 and 6.3 it was just deploy on device. Here I am not seeing that kind of option.

Comment: IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20160318-1808 is used

Answer (score 0):

1) By design of Microsoft, Windows 8 Universal project comes with 3 projects within - Windows 8.1, Windows Phone 8.1 and shared. 
Note that this is different from the Windows Phone Silverlight project.

2) Direct update feature is available only in Windows Phone Silverlight and not Windows Universal.

Comment: Initially I added WP Silverlight but didn't received direct update on device. Later I thought it may be in Universal. Again I reverted to WP Silverlight. Still WP8 device is not receiving direct update. WL.Client.connect() is giving success. Android and IOS devices are getting direct update but none of the WP8 devices are getting direct update.

Comment: Direct update is available only in Silverlight. Deploy the modified .wlapp and let the client connect to the server. After this what is happening? Do you see the direct update pop-up or nothing at all? What exactly is happening

Comment: No direct update popup on WindowsPhone8. But same popup is seeing on Android and IOS for each modifications deployments. As I mentioned in above comment WL.Client.connect() is giving success. Tried same on 6.3, WP8 device getting direct update. Is there any issue with IFix which am using?